# Equivalent of ViewData["MenuItem.StoreMenuId"] using ViewBag? ViewBag.MenuItem.StoreMenuId doesn't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, viewbag, viewdata

Is it possible to convert `ViewData["MenuItem.StoreMenuId"]` to ViewBag? I use ViewBags to store `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so I can bind to `@Html.DropdownListFor` in my views. This works fine if its a simple property that isn't nested (i.e., StoreMenuId):

**ViewBag:**

```
ViewBag.StoreMenuId = new SelectList(_db.StoreMenus.Where(m => m.Store.Id == model.StoreId), "Id", "Name");
```

**DropDownListFor:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StoreMenuId, null, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

---

But what if the property is nested (i.e., MenuItem.StoreMenuId)? **This doesn't work:**

**ViewBag:**

```
ViewBag.MenuItem.StoreMenuId = new SelectList(_db.StoreMenus.Where(m => m.Store.Id == model.StoreId), "Id", "Name");
```

**DropDownListFor:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MenuItem.StoreMenuId, null, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

---

What ends up working is changing `ViewBag.MenuItem.StoreMenuId` to `ViewData["MenuItem.StoreMenuId"]` **This works**:

**ViewData:**

```
ViewData["MenuItem.StoreMenuId"] = new SelectList(_db.StoreMenus.Where(m => m.Store.Id == model.StoreId), "Id", "Name");
```

**DropDownListFor:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MenuItem.StoreMenuId, null, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: The dictionary needs a key.`"MenuItem.StoreMenuId"` is a single string key. But when you try to do `ViewBag.MenuItem.StoreMenuId`, It wont work as the dynamic dictionary would like to have a simply key. But why are you taking the trouble like this ? Why not simply use a single key ?

Comment: I guess I have to use `ViewData["MenuItem.StoreMenuId"]`. The reason I'm doing this is because I have a single view with multiple forms. The model I pass to the view contains a MenuItem model as a property and the MenuItem model contains a StoreMenuId property. So I need to bind to "MenuItem.StoreMenuId"